# Does a creature provoke opportunity attacks while riding a carpet of flying?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, opportunity-attack

The [carpet of flying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/carpet-of-flying) says:

> You can speak the carpet's command word as an action to make the carpet hover and fly. It moves according to your spoken directions, provided you are within 30 feet of it.

If a creature is riding this carpet and leaves the reach of an enemy creature, do they provoke an opportunity attack from them? Specifically, does using an action to command the carpet to move (which then moves you) count as using your action to move for the purposes of provoking an opportunity attack?

Comment: Somewhat related on [How does mounted combat work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63646/how-does-mounted-combat-work)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No, because the Action is not used to move

If you had to use your Action to make the carpet fly, then you definitely would provoke an opportunity attack, because you only avoid that when:

> you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction. (PHB, p. 195)

However, [the consensus is](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123090/does-it-take-your-action-every-turn-to-make-a-flying-carpet-move) that a carpet of flying does not require your Action to move, but rather to activate. The spoken directions you deliver to it are not an action, but something you can do in your turn without spending any resources since:

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move.
>
> You can communicate however you are able, through brief utterances and gestures, as you take your turn. (PHB, p. 190)

### The Carpet Doesn't Provoke Opportunity Attacks Either

If you considered a carpet's rider to be "mounted" on the carpet, one might be tempted to make the argument that the carpet itself provokes an Opportunity Attack, and the rider would then be attackable as well since:

> if the mount provokes an opportunity attack while you’re on it, the attacker can target you
> or the mount. (PHB, p. 198)

However, a carpet of flying is an item, not a creature. And the rules state:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile **creature** that you can see moves out of your reach. (PHB, p. 195, bold added)

Thus the carpet does not provoke opportunity attacks itself.

Comment: I like that you included the part that talk about talking as part of your turn. +1 all around.

Comment: Thanks. I also wanted to point out (in a comment since it's not part of the answer) that this is less cheesy than it might sound. After all, most carpets have a flying speed of 60 feet or less, and a simple mounted riding horse can take the disengage action and still move that far in a round without its rider or it suffering Opportunity Attacks.

Comment: (Of course, flying is pretty awesome, but by level 11 [minimum recommended level for a very rare magic item] a party could have plenty of ways of getting that into the mix.)

Answer (score 6):

## Moving the carpet does not take an action and thus no opportunity attacks are provoked

> You can speak the carpet's command word as an action to make the carpet hover and fly. It moves according to your spoken directions, provided you are within 30 feet of it.

The action and the command word are only to make activate the magic item, not to move it around.<sup>1</sup> The second sentence says that all you have to do is speak and the carpet will move accordingly. Since no action cost is listed as being associated with these spoken directions it follows that no action of any kind is needed to perform them.

Thus, this situation falls into the last case outline by the [rules for Opportunity Attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks) which say:

> You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.

Since the carpet is moving you without the rider using movement, action, or reaction then this is a clear case where the rules say that an OA is not provoked by the rider.

Note that the carpet cannot provoke OAs since it is an object (see the sidenote to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134664/28591) for more details on this) so it also does not get any OAs.

---

<sup>1 - Thanks @PlayPatrice for pointing this out to me in [their answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134691/28591) and the comments to it.</sup>

Comment: Cleaner answer than mine.  I just realized I went off on a tangent.

Comment: @PlayPatrice I thought about just kind of prodding you to pare it down a little but I didn't want to be pushy. To your credit you came up with the key piece of the puzzle that made the solution possible. I just thought the mount idea was a little too far afield for my tastes. However, I do think it is an interesting suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

## No, (RAW) The creature has not moved so does not provoke an attack of opportunity while on a moving platform (flying carpet).

**However, it can be argued that the carpet itself is subject to an attack of opportunity**

The character uses a command word (action) to animate the object.  Thereafter, moving the carpet is a free action (spoken words).  They can move the carpet within 30 feet without standing on the carpet, and then take a move.   This means the character can also stand on or off the carpet, not move, and cause the carpet to move.

After that you have two possible interpretations:

- Treat the carpet as a moving platform (No AOA's against the carpet, no extended rules)
- Treat the carpet as a mount

In the first case, it's a moving platform.  No Attacks of opportunity can be made against the carpet or the player so long as the player does not move on the carpet.  This would be a RAW interpretation as there is no explicit evidence of a carpet being explicitly ruled into either an animated construct or mount.

Another interpretation could rule the carpet as being mounted and thus be treated as an animated object.   This would cause the carpet to act as a mount, following [mounted combat](https://5thsrd.org/combat/mounted_combat/) rules. **The interpretation is up to the DM.**  Note that with a large enough carpet, it would cost 5ft of movement to move from the front of the carpet to the back of the carpet (5ft x 7ft or larger).

With mounted combat, the rider isn't moving, and still has access to all of their movement as part of a move action, though mounting and dismounting requires a large expenditure of total movement.  If using the mounted combat rules as an interpretation, the mount itself would incur an attack of opportunity if it moves out of a threatened space.

> if the mount provokes an opportunity attack while you’re on it, the attacker can target you or the mount. (PHB, p. 198)

Also something else to consider from mounted combat:

> If an effect moves your mount against its will while you're on it, you must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity saving throw or fall off the mount, landing prone in a space within 5 feet of it. If you're knocked prone while mounted, you must make the same saving throw.

From here we would need to determine the base stats of the carpet.   One method would be to pull from the [Animate Objects](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Animate%20Objects#content) spell and treating it as a medium or large animated object.  (HP: 40, AC: 13, Str: 10, Dex: 12 - Medium) / (Large - HP: 50, AC: 10, Str: 14, Dex: 10 - Large).

**Overall - with this interpretation rules are vague and you will need to work with the DM regarding the specifics of how to handle mounted flying carpet combat**

Above was my suggestion on how to handle the extended implications.   But to reiterate the core of you question:

Standing on the carpet and telling the carpet to move, does not expend the users move action or allow for opportunity attacks.  Activating the carpet requires an action, telling the carpet to move on subsequent actions is a free action.  Rules as written the carpet is a moving platform and does not itself - provoke attacks of opportunity.

Comment: Note that the carpet of flying is an object and objects do not provoke OAs, only creatures. "You can make an opportunity attack when **a hostile creature** that you can see moves out of your reach." So, I don't think it really can be argued that the carpet provokes at all.

Comment: Animated objects created by the Animate Objects spell do incur attacks of opportunity.   The carpet is an animated object.   Does this mean a passive animal (draft horse) with no intention of attacking, does not provoke AOA's while mounted (since it can't attack while being ridden and controlled)?

Either way I suggested it as an alternate interpretation.  And clearly stated it as such.   I do like your comment.

Comment: Animated Objects are no longer objects when Animated - they turned into creatures by the spell. The Carpet of Flying does not call itself a creature.

Comment: You are correct that objects under the effects of *animate objects* do provoke OAs, but that is because the spell itself says that the object become a creature. Do you have a source for saying that a carpet of flying is at all related to the *animate objects* spell? It doesn't say so in the description I am looking at. Fwiw, a draft horse is a creature and would provoke OAs like normal.

Comment: Okay, With what you guys have said, I will concede that there is no explicit statement that the carpet is an animated object.   But is an object, it is animated by magic, and it is a construct (Moving, non-living thing).  I would chalk this up to a "Common Sense" ruling.  In this case the carpet is fulfilling all of the roles of a mount - and could be argued needs to follow the rules of mounted combat.  I've clearly separated the ideas (moving platform VS Mounted) and given explanations of how to handle it if interpreted as mounted combat.

Comment: Speaking the command word is an action (I clearly stated that) - This makes the carpet hover and fly.  It moves according to your spoken directions, provided that you are within 30 feet of it. - so after it is hovering / flying - it moves according to spoken directions *free action to speak*.   The carpet continues to hover / fly without speaking the command word each round.

Comment: ohhh yeah I got it now. Makes sense. Good catch I missed that in the question even. :)

Comment: Do you have any examples of other DMG magic items that aren't objects? If so, do they specifically call that out?

Comment: @NautArch There are magic items that can become creatures upon activation, like the Figurine of Wondrous Power (DMG, p. 169). But that item states "f you use an action to speak the command word and throw the figurine to a point on the ground within 60 feet of you, **the figurine becomes a living creature.**"

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme That was my thought as well. Suggesting that common sense is in adding details that aren't there (turning an object into a creature) seems illogical.

Comment: There are cases where taking things too literally causes rule absurdity.  If something has all the properties of X - and doesn't explicitly state that it is NOT X - could we not reasonably conclude that it is X?  Point in case is Wall of Force does not explicitly grant cover or state that it is an obstacle.  It does have all the properties of an obstacle - but does grant cover because it acts as an obstacle - fulfills all necessary roles as a physical obstacle - so it is treated as an obstacle and thus grants cover.

Comment: I don't think I can agree with that argument. Changing the type of something in 5e is a *big deal*. Determining that something acts as cover isn't the same thing. There are definitely rules absurdities, but I don't think this is one.

Comment: I am good with that.   At least you understand where my reasoning comes from.  I have deliberately worded my argument as an alternate interpretation with the RAW ruling clearly spelled out.